# JQuery hover on last element in hierarchy

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have the following html structure

```
<div>
    text 1
    <div>
        text 2
        <div>
            text 3
            <div>
                text 4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

with the following jquery

```
$('div').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    }
);​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jThC/3/)

When I hover to the last div with text 4, all the above div elements will get the class hover.

Is there a clever way to only put the hover class on the last hovered div element? So when I hover to text 3 only the surrounding div wil get the hover class.

I don't want to wrap the text in a new element since the applied situation is a little more complex than this. I also can not use CSS3.

Comment: can you give that innermost div a classname perhaps?

Comment: do you want to select the parents also ? or only the actual element which is hovered ?

Comment: I really wanted to be able to do this with stopPropagation() but couldn't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @idrumgood: Same here :(

Comment: Nope, the hierarchy is dynamical and changes with the use of ajax

Comment: @Mark: You should still be able to traverse it, find the innermost `div`, and give it a class. Whenever it changes.

Comment: Haha same here, already tried it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On mouse over, add the class to the current element, then remove the class from all its ancestor `div`s using [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents):

```
    function() {
        $(this).addClass("hover").parents('div').removeClass("hover");
    },
```

On mouse out, remove the class from the current element and add the class to its parent `div` using [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent), if its parent is one. This way, when the mouse moves *from* the current `div` *to* its parent `div`, it'll receive the hover effect:

```
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover").parent('div').addClass("hover");
    }
```

The selector that you use in `.parents()` and in `.parent()` must be the same selector that you use with `$()` so you don't affect the wrong elements.

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/5jThC/5)

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$('div').hover(
    function() {
        $('div').removeClass("hover");
        $(this).addClass("hover");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    }
);​
```

Comment: I was thinking about this too, but once you hover from "text 4" to "text 3" I would want the div surrounding "text 3" to have the class hover